# Nested cross validation: how does the outer loop work?

Tags: cross-validation, k-fold

(This is a copy post from the cv stack exchange, but just putting it here as well)

I am planning to implement nested cross-validation, but just had a question about its operation. I know there are lots of posts about nested cv, but none of them (as far as I understand) address my mis-understanding about the process.

**Context**: I found the illustration (*shown below*) in the following blog to be the simplest explanation of what is going on: [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/10/nested-cross-validation-python.html).

[image: Image of Nested CV]

**Question**: **How does the outer loop work if each of the inner loop cv processes yield a different optimal set of hyperparameters**?

To explain what I mean, I will refer to the image above which has 3 folds in the outer loop, which I will refer to as Fold 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

For the first iteration of the outer loop, we use Fold 1 as the holdout test set  and we pass in Folds 2 & 3 for (Kfold cv) hyper parameter tuning in the inner loop. Let us say this yields a certain set of optimal hyper-parameters: **hyperparameter set A**. Then we train a model with all of Folds 2 & 3 as training data, using set A of hyperparams, and test on Fold 1 - we get **accuracy A**.

Now for the next iteration of the outer loop, use Fold 2 as the test holdout set and pass in Folds 1 & 3 to the inner loop cv process. Let us say this yields a **different** set of optimal hyper-parameters: **hyperparameter set B**. Then we train a model with all of Folds 1 & 3 as training data, using set B of hyperparams, and test on Fold 2 - we get **accuracy B**.

For completeness, we can repeat the above for third iteration of outer loop and obtain some new set of optimal hyper-parameters: **hyperparameter set C**. Then we train a model with all of Folds 1 & 2 as training data, using set C of hyperparams, and test on Fold 3 - we get **accuracy C**.

This is what I am confused about:

- We now have three different models/sets of hyperparameters. How has the outer loop helped us to evaluate the performance in a general setting?
- Can I simply take the average of accuracy A, B, and C? If so, what does that represent?

I hope this question makes sense. I can try to elaborate if required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the idea of nested CV is to end up with multiple models so you can assess the generalized performance and the model variance, rather than ending up with one model with a generalized error.
Every split in the inner loop is meant for training and validating to determine the optimal hyperparameters used in each split on the outer loop, you then can train a the model and test it with those set of hyperparameters.
In your Example, you will end up with three models with three different performance with three different error estimates, you can then include all those in your analysis and have a better generalization.